# F.Promise - cyclic inference

Tags: java, playframework, promise

At first, i tried to cast with Result

```
(Result) deleteDummy().
```

it will compaint you can't cast.

But when i change to ok(), it say cyclic inference

I'm getting a bit confuse here. It keeps saying cyclic inference. It seems like the return not compatible.... any help?

```
public class Delete_Dummy {
    public static F.Promise<Result> delete() {

        F.Promise<Boolean> promise = isDummyThere(); //rest call to check the exist of the dummy

      return promise.map(aBoolean ->
      {
          if(!aBoolean) {
                return badRequest("No..i'm not there");
          }
          return deleteDummy().map(result-> ok()); //<=cyclic inference <<<<
      });
    }

    private static F.Promise<Result> deleteDummy() {
        String url = "some url";
        return WS.url(url)
                .delete()
                .map(response -> {
                    if (response.getStatus() == NO_CONTENT) {

                        return ok("OK..deleted");
                    }
                    return badRequest("you are bad.");
                } // end of Function<WS>
                );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why it would say "cyclic inference", but `badRequest()` seems to have the type `Result` while `deleteDummy().map(result-> ok())` does have the type `Promise<Result>`. They are not compatible with each other.

If you have a callback that results itself in a promised result, you will have to use [`flatMap`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.3/api/java/play/libs/F.Promise.html#flatMap(play.libs.F.Function)). You can combine it with a non-promise value in your if-else by using [`pure`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.3/api/java/play/libs/F.Promise.html#pure(A)):

```
public static F.Promise<Result> delete() {
    F.Promise<Boolean> promise = isDummyThere(); //rest call to check the exist of the dummy

    return promise.flatMap(aBoolean -> {
        if (!aBoolean) {
            return F.Promise.pure(badRequest("No..i'm not there"));
        }
        return deleteDummy().map(result-> ok());
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, man. I think i've overlooked...on the badRequest w/ deletetdummy.. At first, i tried to return promise<Result> for isDummyThere.. But, it is seem like not possible to retrieve the body of the Result..Then, i've to create another method to return promise<Boolean> to solve this limitation...